# how to bind numbers into Dropdownlist from database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

how to bind numbers  into Dropdownlist from database?
(i want to bind 10,20,30.....upto 2000 later my requirement may change to 5,10,15,20--2000,) 
I have a column in database that should bind to  dropdownlist  need a common logic to bind dropdownlist items
 please help me out on this issue...

Comment: You want Data generation logic or Binding logic?

Comment: I need binding logic....

Comment: Have you tried this http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4d9083/binding-dropdownlist-in-mvc-in-various-ways-in-mvc-with-data/

Answer (score 0):

Create your models:

```
public class myViewModel{
    public int selectedIndex { get; set; } //one for selected index
    public List<myItemsModel> mylist { get; set; } // one for list
}
```

Populate your models:

```
public ActionResult myView() {
    myViewModel model = new myViewModel();
    model.selectedIndex  = aninteger;
    model.mylist = (from blah in blahblah .....);
    return View(model);
}
```

In your view:

```
//Bind the model
@model myProject.Models.myViewModel

//Bind the 2 view models to the control
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.selectedIndex , new SelectList(Model.mylist, "id", "dt", Model.selectedIndex), "Placeholder", new { onchange = @"this.form.submit();", @class = "your css class" })
```